# Conditionals in an Active Record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a large database of information. They are mostly patients. Some of them have email addresses and some of them don't.  I can pull an additional email address by simply running

```
Patient.last.email
```

However I only want to see the patients who do not have email addresses.  (I think its about half of the ones that I have)

I've tried both these below, but not having the best of luck.

```
Patient.includes(:email).where('email = ?', 'nil')
Patient.includes(:email).where('email = ?' 'nil').references(:email)
```

Would anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What does your data look like.  You are talking like emails is a seperate model but referencing it like it is a field on the Patient.

Comment: It is a field within a patient.

Comment: In that case it would be `Patient.where(email: nil)`. `includes` is for joining model tables where `Email` would be a separate model not an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple then.

```
Patient.where(email: nil)
```

Should get you your result.